# Removing R package Rcpp completely

Tags: r, rcpp

I installed package `Rcpp` as follows:

```
    install.packages("/home/R_Libraries/Rcpp_0.11.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I tried removing the package using the following command:

```
    > remove.packages("Rcpp")
    Removing package from '/opt/vertica/R/library'
    (as 'lib' is unspecified)
    Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
    Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

But when I try the library command it seems to load Rcpp library.

```
    library(Rcpp)
```

Could someone let me know how to remove Rcpp package completely from the system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type in the command `.libPaths()` and you should see something like this:

```
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library"
```

Navigate to those folders on your system and remove package folder for `Rcpp`

Comment: `get('.__NAMESPACE__.', envir = asNamespace('Rcpp'))$path`

Comment: For completeness, on a Linux system it may look like this: `[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"       "/usr/lib/R/library"` -- and this before you add non-standard variants like Vertica.

Comment: I did try the libPaths command...It points to only the following library: > .libPaths() --> [1] "/opt/vertica/R/library". It is not showing any other libraries. As Dirk pointed, this is a Vertica version of R and we do not have any other version of R installed in our system.

Comment: Doesn't Vertica (or more precisely its R binding) _depend_ on Rcpp?  You may cripple your installation if you remove Rcpp.

Comment: Dirk...I wasn't aware of it...I was trying to install plyr package and I had to install Rcpp to get plyr to work...Not sure if this installation replaced the older version of Rcpp...Now the R UDFs created in Vertica not working...Will installing the older version of Rcpp (corresponding to Vertica R version) fix this issue?

Comment: Installing the older version of Rcpp package did the trick and the Vertica R is working as expected.